Strange colorization with my DE
I have Kubuntu 24.04 installed, I added the oibaf repo for my video drivers (amd video card), and all was working fine till yesterday. FYI: I've been using this video card with oibaf since Kubuntu version 20.04.
Yesterday there was an update for the video (typically there is one everyday), there was also a system update that requested a reboot. After the system came back up all my reds/oranges were blue, and all my blues were orange. When I say all, I mean all: desktop background, icons, windows, everything. First thought: video card failing, tested with other OS's, works fine.
Tried changing color schemes and individual settings, nothing worked. Waited till today for another update, made no difference. Thinking something got messed up in my user settings under KDE, might have to reset user.
FYI: this is a new setup, not upgraded from previous version. Any thoughts would be great.

There is no hint of your hardware.  inxi -b would help a lot. Copy the output of that command into your question
